# How combine multiple Directory.EnumerateFiles with multiple search criteria taking the most current

Tags: c#, linq

I have directories that contain product files.  The request was to fetch the most current files of specific names and return them in a WebAPI.

I am executing multiple Directory.EnumerateFiles to get a set of files that match. My code works but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to accomplish this using the First and Concatenate options.

The end goal is to get a list of the most current 3 files that match the current criteria

Current code (works):

```
string orderNum = "123465";

string[] s1 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathSetting, "*" + orderNum+ "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                       .Where(name => name.Contains("red") && !name.StartsWith("H"))
                       .OrderByDescending(file => new FileInfo(file).LastWriteTime)
                       .ToArray();

string[] s2 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathSetting, "*" + orderNum+ "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                       .Where(name => name.Contains("red") && name.StartsWith("H"))
                       .OrderByDescending(file => new FileInfo(file).LastWriteTime)
                       .ToArray();

string[] s3 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathSetting, "*" + orderNum+ "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                       .Where(name => name.Contains("blue") && !name.StartsWith("H"))
                       .OrderByDescending(file => new FileInfo(file).LastWriteTime)
                       .ToArray();

int sourceArrayLength = (s1.Length > 0 ? 1 : 0) +
                        (s2.Length > 0 ? 1 : 0) +
                        (s3.Length > 0 ? 1 : 0);

string[] sourceFiles = new string[sourceArrayLength];

if (s1.Length > 0)
{
  sourceFiles[arrayCount] = s1[0];
  arrayCount++;
}

if (s2.Length > 0)
{
  sourceFiles[arrayCount] = s2[0];
  arrayCount++;
}

if (s3.Length > 0)
{
  sourceFiles[arrayCount] = s3[0];
  arrayCount++;
}

// perform action on the files
```

I was attempting something like this (with failure):

```
string[] sFull = Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathSetting, "*" + orderNum+ "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                          .First(name => name.Contains("red") && name.StartsWith("H"))
                          .OrderByDescending(file => new FileInfo(file).LastWriteTime)
         .Concat(Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathSetting, "*" + esoi + "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                          .First(name => name.Contains("red") && !name.StartsWith("H"))
                          .OrderByDescending(file => new FileInfo(file).LastWriteTime))
         .Concat(Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathSetting, "*" + esoi + "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                          .First(name => name.Contains("blue") && name.StartsWith("H"))
                          .OrderByDescending(file => new FileInfo(file).LastWriteTime))
         .ToArray();
```

The issue in this is I cannot OrderByDescending.  I also tried Directory.GetFiles but that had limitations as well.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Do you just want the first file from each enumerable?

Comment: Yes, the first, most recently dated one.

Comment: Which version of C# are you using?

Comment: 6 in a .Net 6.0 project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify your code by using a single call to `Directory.EnumerateFiles` and then filtering and ordering the results by using LINQ. Here is a possible way to do it:

```
string orderNum = "123465";

// Get all files that match the order number
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathSetting, "*" + orderNum + "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);


// Filter and order the files by the criteria
var s1 = files.Where(name => name.Contains("red") && !name.StartsWith("H"))
              .OrderByDescending(file => new FileInfo(file).LastWriteTime)
              .FirstOrDefault(); // Get the first file or null if none

var s2 = files.Where(name => name.Contains("red") && name.StartsWith("H"))
              .OrderByDescending(file => new FileInfo(file).LastWriteTime)
              .FirstOrDefault();

var s3 = files.Where(name => name.Contains("blue") && !name.StartsWith("H"))
              .OrderByDescending(file => new FileInfo(file).LastWriteTime)
              .FirstOrDefault();

// Create a list of the files that are not null
var sourceFiles = new List<string>();
if (s1 != null) sourceFiles.Add(s1);
if (s2 != null) sourceFiles.Add(s2);
if (s3 != null) sourceFiles.Add(s3);

// Perform action on the files
```

Another approach to avoiding the repetition of conditions is to use `specification pattern`.

Comment: That is still three calls to EnumerateFiles.

Comment: If you use Directory.GetFiles then it will only be one iteration at the filesystem level.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more efficient, you would avoid the disk I/O by only iterating over that part once. You might as well use DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles as you need the LastWriteTime for every candidate file.

I suspect there is some way to do it in LINQ that will not make you cry when you come to adjust it, but the old-fashioned way is likely to work well:

```
string searchPattern = "*" + orderNum + "*.txt";

var di = new DirectoryInfo(pathSetting);

var ff = di.EnumerateFiles(searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

var noH = "";
var noHDate = DateTime.MinValue;
var withH = "";
var withHDate = DateTime.MinValue;
var blue = "";
var blueDate = DateTime.MinValue;

foreach (var fi in ff)
{
    if (fi.Name.Contains("red", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        if (fi.Name.StartsWith("H"))
        {
            if (fi.LastWriteTime > withHDate)
            {
                withH = fi.FullName;
                withHDate = fi.LastWriteTime;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (fi.LastWriteTime > noHDate)
            {
                noH = fi.FullName;
                noHDate = fi.LastWriteTime;
            }
        }
    }

    if (fi.Name.Contains("blue", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        && !fi.Name.StartsWith("H"))    {
        if (fi.LastWriteTime > blueDate)
        {
            blue = fi.FullName;
            blueDate = fi.LastWriteTime;
        }
    };

}
```